Why does SSIM in pytorch-mssim need the data range to be specified?
The SSIM metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity_index_measure) formulas do not seem to depend on the range of the values the pixel have (from 0 to 1, from 0 to 255, or any other normalization).
I want to use the SSIM metric for my pytorch model as a loss (by doing len(batch)*(1-SSIM(X,Y,size_average=True))), therefore I'm using the pytorch-mssim library (https://github.com/VainF/pytorch-msssim). The formulas are consistent with what I can see on Wikipedia however, the class SSIM has an argument data_range which I do not understand since it should not affect the result of the SSIM metric. Especially since in my case I use percentile normalization and hence do not know my data_range in advance.

From the original paper, you can see that the authors uses the dynamic range of the image in the computation of C.

Link: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1284395

So those values (min and max) come into play when C is calculated?

Exactly. L is there to put C in a valid range for the pixel values of the image.
